# Win32 dispatch program and redirect stdout to file buffer problem?

Tags: c, winapi, redirect, console, pipe

On Wi32 
I am trying to start a executable who redirects to a filename (current date) e.g. the same as:

Someexecutable.exe > 20101220000000.txt

When I do this from windows cmd.exe everything works fine. However when doing this from my program as shown below the system seems ot either drop the redirect even if it creates the file and/or it seems to buffer a large amount of data before flushing to disk.
I can't change the executable that is being run.
The program beeing executed now only writes to stdout, but remember I can't change this at all. (the simplest way woud be to just do stdout = filehandle; but I that is sadly impossible for me right now!)

(Not required: Also the program waits as system() this is not required but what is the simplest way of detaching the program being run via system() )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char   execstr[512];
  char   s[30];
  size_t i;
  struct tm tim;
  time_t now;

  now = time(NULL);
  tim = *(localtime(&now));
  i   = strftime(s,30,"%Y%m%d%H%M",&tim);

  sprintf(execstr,"someexecutable.exe > %s.txt",s);
  printf("Executing: \"%s\"\n",execstr);

  system(execstr);
  exit(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if someexecutable.exe executes properly when run through system()? AFAIK, this should work just fine...

Comment: someexecutable.exe executes without any problems yes. The behavior described only happens when run from this code for some reason. I assume it must be some buffering going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason for this to not work, but if this is the case with you, one of the alternative solution could be to use popen and then read from the pipe for writing in the desired file. Here is some sample code which is printing on the screen. You can write that to file instead of screen/console as per your requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char   execstr[512];
  char   s[30];
  size_t i;
  struct tm tim;
  time_t now;
  char   buf[128];
  FILE   *pipe;

  now = time(NULL);
  tim = *(localtime(&now));
  i   = strftime(s,30,"%Y%m%d%H%M",&tim);

#if 0
  sprintf(execstr,"a.exe > %s.txt",s);
  printf("Executing: \"%s\"\n",execstr);
#endif /* #if 0 */

   if( (pipe = _popen("a.exe", "rt")) == NULL )
      exit( 1 );

   while(!feof(pipe))
   {
      if (fgets(buf, 128, pipe) != NULL )
         printf(buf);   /* write to the required file here */
   }

   _pclose(pipe);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works a whole lot better- especially if I reduce the buffer to less than 128 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine for me (testing in VS 2010).  Some problems you might run into if you're running your tests in the IDE are:

- the current directory for the program might not be what you expect it to be (so you might be looking for the output file in the wrong place). By default, the current directory for the program when run in the IDE will be the directory that has the project file (whatever.vcproj or whatever,.vcxproj) - not the directory that has the executable.  This can be changed in the project settings.
- the IDE's path might not be the same as what you get at a standard command line, so you program might not be finding `someexecutable.exe`

If you change you program so that the line with the `sprintf()` call looks like:

```
sprintf(execstr,"someexecutable.exe",s);
```

Do you see the output of `someexecutable.exe` in the console window?

Comment: Yes of course I see the output. The problem is not with the 'someexecutable.exe' but rather some kind of buffering going on. E.g. not all data are piped to file.